# best practices about css selectors?

Tags: css, selector

When working with css selectors we face many choices how to select an element (using combined selectors, using ids or classes). I am asking if there are any guidelines and best practices about how to make a choice about selectors and classes/ids to have maintainable websites with easy portable parts ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting your question right, the choice on which selectors to use will depend on good mark-up as well as appropriate naming of classes and ID's.

Generally, know your target audience and what browsers they use. For instance, you can use something like:

p + ul in IE7, but only if, in your html code there are no comments or elements between a p and the next element, which in this case is a ul.

So knowing what browsers your site is dominantly viewied with is the first thing really. Then, you can work backward or forward as needed.

In the end, it's about IE7+ and whether your user base is using that because there are many kinds/types of selectors that only work in later browsers.